# Javascript: List Files in Directory on Server

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to list all files in a particular directory on the server using Javascript? If so, how? I  am not allowed to use platforms which require server side installation. I mean platforms like node.js and such.

Comment: It depends on what the server tells you, so obviously you'd need some sort access to the server.

Comment: The closest solution is make an XHR call, but you'd have to use a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

Well how would you list the server side files if you have no access to server side ?
"I am not allowed to use platforms which require server side installation."

There are some workarounds for this problem, but these usually needs some extra enabled flags from the user side. http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: Ah I'm sorry. I don't really know how to call it. What I meant was I'm not allowed to use platforms like node.js, etc.

Comment: If you have the server you should make sure what's enabled, Apache, Nginx ... ?

Comment: I'm intending to use free hosting. I'll only need this page for a short time and I don't own a server. Currently I'm using 000webhost.com.

Comment: Then you have support for PHP on server side, create small script which lists the directory files. Now you only have to call some XHR request on client side to show the result or use the scripts result directly.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not allowed to use platforms which require server side installation.

You need some server side handler for this request. But may be you already have something. For example mod_autoindex for apache..